# Chrome cannot show which data is used and which data in unused in a css or js file

Tags: google-chrome, inspect-element

I want to know which css and javascript code is used or unused in my page. I can see which files how much percentage is used or unused in coverage tab.

[image]

But I want to know what data is used or unused in a specific file that chrome cant show me. I tried reinstalling google chrome but it didn`t work
how can I fix that?

[image]